# How to implement a Mapbox in your react app?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am trying to implement a mapbox in my web app.following this tutorial https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/ ...
I am facing an error "Error: Invalid type: 'container' must be a String or HTMLElement."
here is my code

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ReactMapGL from 'react-map-gl'
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';


 // eslint-disable-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax


function Map(){
  const mapContainer = useRef(null);
  const map = useRef(null);
  const [lng, setLng] = useState(-70.9);
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(42.35);
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(9);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (map.current) return; // initialize map only once
    map.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainer.current,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [lng, lat],
      zoom: zoom
    });
  });
    return(
        <ReactMapGL >

        </ReactMapGL>
      
    )
}
export default Map;
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used Mapbox but per what I see, you are passing to the container your `mapContainer.current`, which as per your initialization it is null, your declaration is: `const mapContainer = useRef(null));`

You should assign your ref to a React Component or an HTML tag and render it in the dom like:

```
<div ref={mapContainer} />
```

This should fix the error but I'm unaware if it is enough to make the Mapbox to render.